# `figure_align` latex option not read in sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have some trouble with the figure position. I just want to fix them and I found out that, for the `latexpdf` compilation, latex requires the `'figure_align':'H'` option, as described in the [sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-latex_elements).

So I edited my `conf.py` and, the part of `latex_elements` looks like:

```
latex_elements = {
    'papersize':'a4paper',
    'pointsize':'11pt',
    'figure_align':'H'
    }
```

Unfortunately this option is not read during the compilation and the figures are floated in wrong places.

Indeed, the figures in the `file.tex` file look like:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\scalebox{0.500000}{\includegraphics{wel_1.png}}
\end{figure}
```

still `htbp` and not `H` as parameter.

What am I missing?

Comment: The only way I found to make it work is to build in latex `make latex` and then in the `*.tex` file run a **Find & Replace** and replacing all the `htbp` with `H`...

Comment: The `figure_align` option was added in Sphinx 1.3. Are you running an older version of Sphinx?